# How to do small edit to XFA form using Adobe Acrobat

Tags: pdf, adobe, xfa

I have several PDF forms in XFA format that I need to change a single line of text in.  The problem is that they have a massive number of equations & other fillable areas built into them.  The only thing I can see to do is convert them into a standard PDF & recreate all of the fillable/equation based cells on my own.

Is there any way to do a simple text edit on an XFA form without losing all of the existing cells?

Comment: Is the change you are making in the XFA data or is it in some static portion?

Comment: @KevinBrown It is in the static portion.  I just need to alter the statement on where the sheet needs to be sent.

Comment: Static XFA or dynamic?

Comment: I believe it is dynamic but I'm not 100% sure.  I didn't set up the form originally.  @joelgeraci

Comment: Try opening the file in a browser, if you see a form, it's static. If you see a page that starts with "Please wait...", then it's dynamic. If it's dynamic then it's pretty easy to just replace some text because it's stored as XML in the PDF. If it's static, then you need to edit the base page and replace the one that's there.